# oozie fork join is not working after all the nodes are successful

Tags: oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, fork-join, oozie-coordinator

I got into a weird problem in oozie where the fork join sometimes works and sometime doesn't. I also have a decision node before the join.
Due to this my oozie job stuck in **running** state for infinite time.

Both the nodes before join are success and updated in DB as well. Also there is no error in oozie logs. Compared with other successful job the logs are same till that point. But after the job is stuck there are no logs.

Any pointers to debug the issue will be really helpful. For reference i am adding a screenshot as well.

[image]

oozie version: 4.2.0

Update: I have seen this issue is not due to decision node. I am getting this issue in random places where ever i have a join.